# Typical approach to handling late asynchronous callbacks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I'm new to web application development using Javascript.

As Javascript applications appear to work highly asynchronous i'm wondering if there is a common approach to handling callbacks that are invoked too late.
For example assuming an asynchronous request is made and when the response finally comes back the application is in a different state which eventually is not suitable for processing the response.

How would you detect this situation and handle it in case of a successful as well as an error response? Can this issue be solved from a high-level architectural view or will the kind of solution always be tied to the JS framework and/or type of application?

In a related matter is it a recommended pattern for web applications to block input while server-side processing takes place?

Thank You

Comment: Promises pattern is the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick answer to your question is a **Promise**.

Promises are a pattern that may soon be implemented into [ECMA-6](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts), however currently are exercised through your own custom code or the use of libraries such as Kris Kowal's q (see below).

The pattern is fairly simple. You goal is to wrap the asynchronously-executing method or function in order to preserve it's scope and then act on it's return. For most libraries and approaches this is referred to as a then statement.

A simple example:

```
var theEventualResults;

goGetMeSomething().then(function(results) {
  //now I can store the results in my working scope
  theEventualResults = results;
});
```

The idea is that `goGetMeSomething()` returns a "Promise Object" that has a method `then` that executes when goGetMeSomething successfully executes. There are also ways to implement failure, through catching errors or reading failure response codes from requests.

A failure example:

```
var theEventualResults;

goGetMeSomething().then(function(results) {
  //now I can store the results in my working scope
  theEventualResults = results;
}).error(function(reason) {
  //now I can handle the failure, if it fails;
});
```

I would suggest you conduct a little research on Promises and their different implementations in different libraries, to further your grasp. This will also help you find what's best for your specific application.

So, in review of your questions:

1. How would you detect this situation and handle it in case of a successful as well as an error response?

   - **A promise pattern will likely be most useful**
2. Can this issue be solved from a high-level architectural view or will the kind of solution always be tied to the JS framework and/or type of application?

   - **This kind of solution can be implemented in JavaScript independently of any framework. However, if you are using a framework, then it may already have a promise pattern. It is typically useful to implement what the framework offers rather than using something else. [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org) is a good example of this as [Alex C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1628387/alex-c) pointed out.**
3. In a related matter is it a recommended pattern for web applications to block input while server-side processing takes place?

   - **This falls a bit out of scope. I would suggest asking this in a separate question.**

Here are some library references as well:

- Q: https://github.com/kriskowal/q
- RSVP: https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js
- WinJS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211867.aspx

I am not suggesting you use any of these. That's for you to discover. Hopefully, this can help you see the pattern, however, and allow you to decide for yourself.

[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)[q](/questions/tagged/q)[asynchronous](/questions/tagged/asynchronous)[winjs](/questions/tagged/winjs)[rsvp](/questions/tagged/rsvp)[promise](/questions/tagged/promise)

Answer (score 1):

In angularJS, you can use `$q.defer()`, `resolve()`, `reject()` and `promise`, eg:

```
MyObject.myMethod = function(options){

  var deferred = $q.defer();

  myAsyncMethod(options, function(callback_data){
     deferred.resolve(callback_data);
  });  

  return deferred.promise;


};
```

then somewhere else in the code:

```
 var foo = New MyObject();
   foo.myMethod(options).then(function(callback_data){
      // process callback here;
   });
```